# Error with feign client on text/csv response

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-feign, feign

I have an issue with a feign client created for a rest controller in Spring, in this method I write on HttpServletResponse a csv string but when I want to test the feign implementation is showing a console error.

```
feign.codec.DecodeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Void] and content type [text/csv;charset=UTF-8]
```

The feign implementation is:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/report/download")
@Produces('text/csv')
@ApiOperation("Generate a report in csv format")
ResponseEntity<Void> downloadCsv(@PathParam("id") String id)
```

Anyone can help me with this issue please?